# C++ openssl: editing list of elliptic curves

Tags: c++, openssl

I am trying to edit elliptic curves list in openssl.
Now I am trying to set `SSL_OP_NO_TICKET` flag in `SSL_CTX_set_options` method.
By there is not luck.
What I am trying to do is to remove elliptic curves at all.
Will be glad for any help!

**UPDATE**

My code sample:

```
    const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION | SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE | SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION | SSL_OP_NO_TICKET;
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);

    char *list = "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA";
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, list);
    SSL_set_ciphersuites(ssl, list);
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt please?

Comment: @Rup sure, updated my question